# Using the Plaid QuickStart example in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, plaid

I'm trying to get an example of Plaid working in Javascript. I'm following the code from the docs, but I'm not able to get it to work.

First, I generate the link token in Node.js.

```
{
  expiration: '2022-12-07T20:17:05Z',
  link_token: 'link-sandbox-85d50492-cb3b-4046-af2c-faefc1510af5',
  request_id: 'ruUVcZ39O2cEF9J'
}
```

Then, I send this token to the frontend JS example with this code.

```
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = async function(e) {
    var handler = Plaid.create({
    // Create a new link_token to initialize Link
    token: "link-sandbox-85d50492-cb3b-4046-af2c-faefc1510af5",
    receivedRedirectUri: "https://localhost:3000/", // window.location.href,
    onLoad: function() {
        // Optional, called when Link loads
    },
    onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {

    },
    onExit: function(err, metadata) {

    },
    onEvent: function(eventName, metadata) {

    }
    });

    document.getElementById("plaidButton").onclick = function(e) {
        handler.open();
    }
}
</script> 
<button id="plaidButton">Create Link</button>
```

When I click my button to call `handler.open()` I'm getting this error. The React Quickstart example works fine for me, but I'm not able to get it working in plain Javascript.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" from accessing a frame with origin "https://cdn.plaid.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
Error: oauth uri does not contain a valid oauth_state_id query parameter. Request ID: hWvHyyooyWiCmlw
```

I'm running this example locally at https://localhost:3000 and I've also set this as one of my redirect uri's in Plaid.

Answer (score 0):

At least one issue is that the receivedRedirectUri should not be set when initializing Link for the first time. It is used when initializing Link for the second time, after returning from the OAuth redirect.

As to the CORS issue (Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" from accessing a frame with origin "https://cdn.plaid.com"...) I'm not sure about that -- the code you copy and pasted looks fine and when I run it locally I don't get that error, so the issue may be in something you aren't showing here.

For a full working example in JavaScript, check out
https://github.com/plaid/tiny-quickstart/tree/main/vanilla_js